# Best PHP to PDF library for mailing labels/price tags/custom page sizes

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

I'm planning a PHP project that will be replacing the basic (off-line) templates used to generate some Dymo label formats as well as Avery 5160 mailing label sheets.  I've seen numerous mentions of different PHP-to-PDF libraries but none specifically addressing funky page sizes and output.  Does anyone have any recommendations? FPDF seems to be in the lead in this area

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF is based on FPDF, so they are really similar. I wrote a project on FPDF and could switch to TCPDF without any modification on the API. TCPDF is backward compatible to FPDF. But it's much smarter, offers a higher range of functionality for the cost of performance. TCPDF was always slower than FPDF.

You can use both FPDF and TCPDF for both "funky page sizes" and output.

You can specify a custom page size (e.g. 123 width by 456 height) within the [constructor](http://www.id.uzh.ch/cl/zinfo/fpdf/doc/fpdf.htm):

```
$pdf = new FPDF("P", "pt", array(123, 456)); //"P" as portrait orinetaion, pt as measures used
```

Like I said TCPDF is the same. It has some more attributes tho: [TCPDF::__construct](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a134232ae3ad1ec186ed45046f94b7755)

As for the funky output, I think, for label design you'll need Line and Curve or Circle. Both of them knows [Line](http://www.id.uzh.ch/cl/zinfo/fpdf/doc/line.htm), but Curve is a bit more problematic. TCPDF has built in [Circle](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a7e7f5d97a5c33e2245d3860aed35a593) and [Curve](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a23895bb8d9fae071308f9d307ea638fd) but FPDF needs an [ADD-ON](http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/69/) for that.